# Odoo 10 - XMLRPC getting description of a select field

Tags: xml-rpc, odoo-10, odoo

I am retrieving `stock.picking` record via XMLRPC:

```
record = api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'stock.picking', 'read', [[1]])
```

Which returns all fields from the record.

Among all fields, I am interested in field `state`, which can be accessed via:

```
record.state
```

Which contains:

```
done, draft, partially_available, etc.
```

How do I get the translated description for that state via XMLRPC

Comment: Nothing, as I can't find anything in XMLRPC documentation.Any tip or guidance is welcomed so at least I can start.